# How do I check out specific version of a project on visual studio devops using git?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

I have a project in Visual Studio Devops that I have checked code into on a daily basis for many months. I need a specific version of the project from a stable cutoff date but don't know how to check out all the files from just that date.

How can I check out all of the files in a project as of a specific time in the past?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't think of git in terms of dates, but in terms of commits.

Before proceeding, I am assuming you are familiar with `git log` output.
If not, a refresher: it lists all the commits in the repository, starting from the most recent one.
The information listed is: Commit hash code(SHA), Author, Date and Message. However, `git log` can be customized to help you solve your problem.

For example, let's say that the date you are interested in is June 20 2019.

To list all the commits from that date, run:
`git log --since="jun 20 2019" --until="jun 21 2019"`

From here, there are three possible scenarios:

1. There's exactly one commit in the list.
   Great!
   This is the commit you are looking for.
   Go to **Solution**
2. There is more than one commit in the list.
   Well...
   I can't help you there, you need to examine them and decide which one is the one you're interested in.
   If you are very specific about the date thing, just choose the most recent one in the list, and go to **Solution**.
3. There are no commits in the list.
   No commits were made on that specific date.
   But if you want to know the state of the source on that date, that means you are interested in commits which happened *before* that date.
   Broaden the search using `git log --since="jun 19 2019" --until="jun 21 2019"`.
   Alternatively, you can provide only the upper limit to the `log` command by omitting the `--since="jun 19 2019"` from the options.
   Either way, choose the commit you are interested in, and go to **Solution**.

**Solution**:

Copy the hash code (SHA) of the selected commit and then run `git checkout <SHA>` - this will bring your repository to the state corresponding to that commit.
You will be in a so-called "detached head" state, which sounds horrible, but nothing to worry about.
If you are just exploring/building but not making any changes to the code that you'd like to save, you are ok.
If you want to go back, run `git checkout <branch you want to go back to>`.

If you'd like to branch of from there, run `git checkout -b <name of your new branch>`.

If you are sure you will be modifying, you can combine the previous two commands in this one-liner, which creates a new branch based on the commit you were looking for: `git checkout -b <name of your new branch> <SHA>`.